# Unable to create user programmatically in drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

while I attempt to create user in drupal 8 programmatically it is show me following error

1.)Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Field type is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 783 of /home/printhouseheroes/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
2.)InvalidArgumentException: Field type is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 586 of /home/printhouseheroes/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).

code for creating user is as below

```
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();



 $user = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::create();
  $user->setPassword($form_state->getValue('pass'));
  $user->enforceIsNew();
  $user->setEmail('test@test.com');
  $user->setUsername('test_test');//This username must be unique and accept only a-Z,0-9, - _ @ .
  $user->set("init", 'test@test.com');
  $user->set("langcode", $language);
  $user->set("preferred_langcode", $language);
  $user->set("preferred_admin_langcode", $language);
  $user->activate();
  $user->save();
```

Kindly suggest

Comment: I guess some of $user->set() calls are failing. Try removing them one by one to see what causes that error.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this

```
$user->set("init", 'test@test.com');
```

for this

```
$user->set("init", 'email');
```